# Magic mouse two button click stopped working

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse

My Magic mouse two finger right click stopped working 4 days ago. I can use the control click combo to right click but the mouse was way more convenient. I have not changed any settings, it just stopped working.

I am using a Macbook pro 15", both were purchased togeather about two weeks ago and worked fine until 4 days ago.

I googled around and could not find any suggestions to get it fixed, does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) will do this.

Go to its preferences.

[image: BetterTouchTool Prefs]

Then make your settings look like this window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'two finger right click', are you touching the mouse with two fingers at the same time?

The right click only works if you touch it with one finger on the right hand side. It's easy to use two fingers by accident, but you have to lift your first finger and click only with the second to trigger the right click behaviour.

I used a traditional clicky mouse before my Magic Mouse, where you can happily rest both fingers on the mouse while clicking either side, so the Magic Mouse took a bit of getting used to and this tripped me up too.

Comment: Thanks for the response, you can also tap the mouse with two fingers to right click. This was working, until 4 days ago. I have been googling like crazy and i found out that an update last week killed that function. I guess i have to wait until a patch comes out.

Answer (score 0):

There was an update that caused the two-button click to fail; maybe the next update will take it back.